# my mule service is deleting file immediately , how to delete a file after completely updated to the db?

Tags: java, mule

- In my mule service file is deleting immediately when starting the application ,if i stopped the application in the middle of the operation i losing the file with out processing  i want to delete the file in the mule service based on my acknowledgement using java code

i tried like in the following code
Please find the below code :

```
<file:connector
        name="nonStreamingFileConnector"
        streaming="false"
        autoDelete="true" doc:name="File" validateConnections="true"/>
```

Comment: Paste your entire configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we have to user move file pattern

Answer (score 0):

Try to make `autoDelete= "false"`. So that file won't be deleted as soon as file picked for processing and then use your other code to delete the file. But make your of polling frequency. Because it will start reading the file by every 1000 milisec. So as per your processing time try to increase the pollingFrequency value till you delete the file based on your requirement.

```
   <file:connector
    name="nonStreamingFileConnector"
    streaming="true"
    autoDelete="false" doc:name="File" validateConnections="true"/>

    <file:inbound-endpoint path="c:/in" connector-ref="File" pollingFrequency="60000" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>
```

Comment: if we used your snippet u should expect file operation time .. you cant expect  time period to process one csv  . the csv may contain laks of records,, it may take 1 hr to process one file..

Answer (score 0):

Another option that i use with the file connector is called **Move to Directory** so once the file is read into the flow the file will be moved to another folder that you can go back and grab the file again.